# PHP in URLs - how to add 'or' to queries (instead of x&y&z, x or y or z)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress plugin which redirects to a random post. It allows me to redirect to random posts based on tags, so the url might look like

```
example.com/?random&random_tag_id=100
```

If I wanted to find random posts which are tagged with tag ids 100 and 101, I would just do

```
example.com/?random&random_tag_id=100&random_tag_id=101
```

But I want to find random posts which are from EITHER ids 100 or 101. I know & is used for 'this + this', but would it be possible to make a 'this OR this' request via the URL?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
example.com/?random&random_tag_id=100,101,102,103
```

You'll then have to do something like this when you process those variables:

```
<?php
$random_tag_ids = explode(',', $_GET['random_tag_id']);
// $random_tag_ids now contains an array of your random tag ids
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arrays to query like this:

```
example.com/?random&random_tag_id[]=100&random_tag_id[]=101
```

You'll get `$_GET['random_tag_id'] == array(100, 101)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing it that way is you'll overwrite the value in PHP. You need bracket notation to pass it correctly as an array

```
example.com/?random&random_tag_id[]=100&random_tag_id[]=101
```

When you get to your PHP then you'll have

```
echo $_GET['random_tag_id'][0]; //Outputs 100
```

You could then pass into your query an imploded list

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how GET parameters work.

In a Query String (`?key=a&otherkey=b`), the `&` is just a delimiter between the different key/var pairs. So the PHP equivalent of that string is this:

```
$_GET['key'] = 'a';
$_GET['otherkey'] = 'b';
```

If you use the same key twice in a query string, the latter will overwrite the former. So for the string `?key=a&key=b`, `$_GET['key']` will be equal to `b`.

As others have said, you can pass data via a comma separated list, (i.e. `?key=1,2,3,4`), or via an array, (i.e. `?key[]=a&key[]=b`).